# jq accepts invalid json input when it should throw an error

Tags: jq

I am having problem to validate json string.
i am using below code

```
if jq -e . >/dev/null 2>&1 <<<"$json_string"; then
        echo "Parsed JSON successfully and got something other than false/null"
    else
        echo "Failed to parse JSON, or got false/null"
    fi
```

This does not work for `json_string={"fruit":{"name":"app`. this still shows **Parsed JSON successfully and got something other than false/null** where as the json string is incomplete.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue, Can you add a complete reproducible example with the shell's shebang and the `json_string` variable assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it is one of the issues in `jq-1.5`. Un-terminated objects/arrays, without a corresponding close character, are being treated as valid objects and are accepted by the parser. Can reproduce in `jq-1.5`, but fixed in `jq-1.6`

On `jq-1.6`

```
jq -e . <<< '{"fruit":{"name":"app'
parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
echo $?
4
```

minimal reproducible example below, which again is handled well in 1.6 but doesn't throw an error in 1.5

```
jq -e . <<< '{'
parse error: Unfinished JSON term at EOF at line 2, column 0
jq -e . <<< '['
parse error: Unfinished JSON term at EOF at line 2, column 0
```

---

Suggest upgrading to `jq-1.6` to make this work!